# Get-or-create id with AngularFire

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-realtime-database

I'd like to create a system that could have a ton of games:

```
var gamePath = new Firebase("https://x.firebaseio.com/games/");
var games = $firebaseObject(gamePath);
games.$bindTo($scope, "games").then(function() {
  // ...
  if (typeof $scope.games[gameId] == "undefined"){
    $scope.games[gameId] = setupEverything(userId);
  }
  else {
    // ...
  }
});
```

I presume that as the list of games becomes longer, this solution becomes unscalable.  I'd like to change the gamePath to user specify a "gameId", but then I'd end up with a null return value.  What's the right angularFire pattern to accomplish this more elegantly?

** Note: the reason I'm using an object in the first place is so that I can conveniently route players to the same game by a gameId.  This simple key-to-game object mapping is important, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Having a `$firebaseObject()` that refers to a list of object is an anti-pattern. If you're referring to a list of objects, use `$firebaseArray()`.

If you want to add a new game to that list, either use `$firebaseArray.$add()` on it or (if you want to control the game ids) just add the game to the Firebase location directly. Since AngularFire is built on top of the Firebase JavaScript SDK, they interoperate perfectly.

```
var gamesPath = new Firebase("https://x.firebaseio.com/games/");
$scope.games = $firebaseArray(gamesPath);
var myGamePath = gamesPath.child(gameId);
$scope.mygame = $firebaseObject(myGamePath).$loaded(function() {
  if (!$scope.mygame.$value) {
    myGamePath.set({
      uid: userId,
      startedAt: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
    })
  };
});
```

With this, the new game will immediately be added to `$scope.games` and set to `$scope.mygame` when `set()` is called.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I'm still a little confused though - if I run this a second time and console "$scope.mygame.$value" I still get undefined.  How can I run the if/else so that I retrieve the value if it is already created?

Also, sidenote, I think your second line has a typo (gamesPath) not (gamePath).

Comment: Typo fixed. Thanks for spotting. `$loaded()` will fire only once. It's a frequently over-used method, most often there is a better solution (that just doesn't seem to be what people look for). For example, if you're trying to wait for a value to appear at a location, I recently wrote a [Gist that shows how to wait for a value with most Firebase SDKs](https://gist.github.com/puf/146fecdae240ac0e62f858f7650aa85f). If you're looking to accomplish the same within AngularFire, see https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/extending-services.html#section-firebaseobject.